# Is there a name for this algorithm? (I've been calling it changeBinary)

Tags: algorithm, binary

Is there a name for this algorithm? (I've been calling it changeBinary)

DESCRIPTION:

You take a binary string as input.

The first bit of the output is the same as the first bit of the input.

Every bit after that is 0 if the bit at that index of the input string is the same as the bit at the previous index in the input string. Otherwise, it's 1.

For example,

Input:  00011000001010100001001000010011

Output: 00010100001111110001101100011010

Here is a simple javascript implementation:

```
var changeBinary = function(binaryString){
  var output = binaryString[0] === '0' ? '0' : 1;
  for (var i = 1; i < binaryString.length; i++){
    var nextBit = binaryString[i] === binaryString[i - 1] ? '0' : '1';
    output += nextBit;
  }
  return output;
}
```

OBSERVATIONS:

First, it seems that if you keep applying the algorithm to a string, it eventually returns to its original value. Second, it the number of iterations it takes to do so seems to always be a power of 2 (including 2^0 = 1). For example, if you apply the changeBinary function above 32 times to the string above, it will return to the original value.

Has anyone ever encountered this before, and if so, do you know of any other information about it?

It just seems to me like this is something so simple and basic that someone must have studied it more in depth.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: interesting....

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code

Answer (score 6):

It may be interesting to know that this is `x ^ (x << 1)` on a BigInteger (or, if you limit the length of the strings, the same thing but on a fixed-size integer), also describable as `clmul(x, 3)`.

Carryless multiplication, which is essentially just like normal multiplication, but instead of adding the partial products you XOR them, has some fairly nice properties, such as being commutative and associative. The associative property is especially of interest since it allows you to reason easily about what composing your algorithm with itself a couple of times does: for example
`changeBinary o changeBinary` is `clmul(clmul(x, 3), 3) = clmul(x, clmul(3, 3)) = clmul(x, 5)`

That it's a carryless multiplication by 3 also explains why it "undoes" itself when applied often enough, as the carryless multiplicative inverse of 3 is the number with all bits set, which with 32 bits is 0xffffffff, which can be formed as 3<sup>31</sup> (with carryless exponentiation). This also follows from the equivalence of a carryless *square* to a "bit-spread", so it takes a bit string abcd to a0b0c0d, and thus `clpow(3, 32) = 1` - 5 spreads have spread the bits so far apart that only the original lsb is left over, the rest does not fit in a 32bit number.

And that also gives a faster inversion, because the number with all bits set can be decomposed into small number of (carryless) factors:

```
3 x 5 x 17 x 257 x 65537 ...
```

With a number of factors that is the base two logarithm of the number of bits (rounded up).

Since `x ^ (x >> 1)` converts a number to Gray Code, I suppose you might call this a "mirrored" Gray Code. The same trick with the factors is used "in the mirror image" to convert a Gray Code back to binary:

```
x ^= x >> 1 // this is like a "mirror" of x = clmul(x, 3)
x ^= x >> 2 //                                         5
x ^= x >> 4 //                                        17
x ^= x >> 8
x ^= x >> 16
```

Here we just flip the direction of the shift to get:

```
x ^= x << 1
x ^= x << 2
x ^= x << 4
x ^= x << 8
x ^= x << 16
```

Which is `clmul(x, 0xffffffff)` and has also been called `PS-XOR(x)`

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you described is an example of [Delta Encoding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding).

Comment: I had considered calling it "binary delta coding." I didn't have it in mind when I first thought about this algorithm, but now that you mention it, it does make me wonder if it could lead to any transformation algorithms that could help with lossless data compression - sort of like Burrows Wheeler. One problem with that, though, is that as the binary input increases in size, the total possible number of cycles to the original value increases to an impossibly large number to test, so it would be a massive (and impractical) brute-force trial and error to find the optimal number of cycles.

Comment: Yes, delta encoding is sometimes used to help with data compression, but I am not sure how much gain one gets doing it on a binary stream.  Delta encoding is often used to reduce the range of values.  Typically the decoding is done directly by reversing the encoding algorithm rather than by cycling.  Without actually looking I would have thought that the binary delta, which is an xor with the state variable, would look pretty similar on the encode and decode and would therefore reverse itself every iteration.

Comment: I started playing around with it a little and I found that repeatedly applying the ChangeBinary() function to a binary string does alter the number zero bits and one bits, but I haven't found any patterns from doing so that suggest it would substantially change the Shannon Entropy of the resulting binary string very much. It's possible that it could under certain circumstances, but what I haven't found is any way of doing so in a direct or systematic way, which is what I think would be needed to even consider making a worthwhile data compression algorithm with it.

Comment: My info theory is a bit rusty, but I thought Shannon's entropy calculation establishes a theoretical bound and is not something can be changed by lossless coding.  Coding, entropy and compression are all rich topics with lots of research papers.  Perhaps you will find some inspiration there.

Comment: Yes, indeed, they are. Shannon Entropy calculates a theoretical lower limit of how much something can be compressed as a function of the probabilities. It doesn't really account for all of the possible permutations that something can be arranged in. That was part of what kind of interested me about trying this algorithm on really large binary data sets.  I was thinking that if the total number of zeros versus ones becomes really imbalanced after a certain number of cycles that it could change the Shannon Entropy of the binary string, but I'm skeptical. Thanks for your insights.